# Disable mouse wheel scroll on Angular Material's md-tabs labels

Tags: javascript, angular-material

With using a desktop browser and scrollable tab labels, the labels scroll with the mouse wheel.
This is annoying when scrolling down a page with some set of tabs and always getting stuck in a tab label scroll.

The behaviour can be seen here: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/tabs
Make window narrow and scroll down to Dynamic Tabs.

I think the relevant code is here:

```
angular.module('material.components.tabs')
    .directive('mdTabScroll', MdTabScroll);

function MdTabScroll ($parse) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    compile: function ($element, attr) {
      var fn = $parse(attr.mdTabScroll, null, true);
      return function ngEventHandler (scope, element) {
        element.on('mousewheel', function (event) {
          scope.$apply(function () { fn(scope, { $event: event }); });
        });
      };
    }
  }
}
MdTabScroll.$inject = ["$parse"];
...
<md-pagination-wrapper md-tab-scroll="$mdTabsCtrl.scroll($event)">
```

Things I've tried:

- removed the "md-tab-scroll" attribute (js, after page load) -> event    is still there
- replaced md-pagination-wrapper innerHTML with a clone of itself -> all events are lost, including clicks

So is there a way to disable the mouse wheel scroll on tab labels? Scrolling by arrow click and swiping is fine.

Github issue: https://github.com/angular/material/issues/8197

Thanks,
Dennis